# ICE fails even with TURN/STUN servers

Tags: webrtc, p2p, stun, videochat, turn

I have implemented video chat. It works perfectly on local, but doesn't work on production server.

```
this.rtc.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
    console.log(this.rtc.iceConnectionState);
}
```

On local server the code above prints: `checking`, then after some time: `connected`
On the production server it's: `checking` then `failed`

I tried to use Google's STUN server and free TURN server by https://numb.viagenie.ca/ (You need to register in order to get access)
I checked both TURN and STUN servers via https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ and it seems work fine.

The code is written in Vue js and you can see it in this pen:
https://codepen.io/4unkur/pen/orNyvy?editors=1010

What is wrong with my code, or is this an issue of that free TURN server?

Dump of chrome://webrtc-internals https://pastebin.com/whhibysu

**UPDATE**

I was testing my app using 2 laptops: HP (Windows) and Macbook and it didn't work. Then I tried to test is using my mobile phone + Macbook and it worked, then phone + HP - didn't work.
So I thought maybe the problem is in HP? So I tested HP + HP i.e. opened 2 tabs in browser on HP and it did work. Why the issue happens only on HP, might it be the issue of Windows OS?

**UPDATE 2**

I run WebRTC Troubleshooter at https://test.webrtc.org/
on HP and it gave me errors in Connectivity tab:

[image]

On Macbook: I don't get such errors

Comment: Your code looks ok and the webrtc-internals dump shows that you have both local and remote relay candidates so this end of the connection should work. But it doesn't.
One potential source of errors is not calling addIceCandidate on the other side which will cause things to fail.

Comment: Could you please tell when should I call addIceCandidate on the other side?

Comment: @PhilippHancke I updated my question. Issue occurs only on certain devices. What can be the problem?